# How can center a div when the screen is on XS using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a div with 4 columns but when the screen is on `xs` I want to center whatever the content is. Here's my code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But on default view it shows the`xs-6` so I got 2 columns. I don't know why because I set my column to `md-3`

Comment: If you want to center it, make it `col-xs-12`

Comment: @Swellar, I have some content but I don't want to become 100% of the witdh because some part looks large on the content.

Comment: Then make it `col-xs-9`, it is smaller and because of the offset, it will be centered and the other divs will be in the next line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to overwrite the lower offsets by using the [`col-*-offset-0`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) classes:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. I didn't notice that piece of code on the docu. :)

Comment: Thanks thats what I need. :)